# Why segmentation fault in the following code?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

This is my code:

```
char * name[]={"Dileep","Avina"};
name[0][1]='A';
```

here name[0] is an char* pointing to string literal "Dileep". So what will be the name[0][1]? Why it is giving me runtime error?

Comment: string-literals are constant, you can't change them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char \*s" but not "char s\[\]"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha)

Comment: Stop using `const char*` or `char*` when writing C++, use `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Dileep" and "Avina" are string constants.  Trying to change them is undefined behavior.  If the OS puts them in read-only memory, you will get a fault.

Answer (score 0):

> name[0] is an char* pointing to string literal "Dileep".

No, `char * name[]` is spurious. `"Dileep"` is [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) with type `const char[7]`, and your code is not allowed since C++11 because of the conversion from string literal to `char *`. `char * name[]={"Dileep","Avina"};` should be `const char * name[]={"Dileep","Avina"};`.

> So what will be the name[0][1]?

It should be a `const char`.

> Why it is giving me runtime error?

Modifying string literal is UB.